# Calling the props from within the class

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to access the this.url property from within the constructor, but I'm getting an error message saying it's undefined.  This seems like normal task that's blocking me from moving forward.

```
export class Something {
  constructor() {
    this.url = 'domain.com';
  }
  static something(param) {
    const url = `${this.url}/dir/tofile`; // ${this.url} is showing as undefined
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: [A static method is shared between all instances of the class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/static), and doesn't have access to a particular instance's variables.

Comment: I obviously still have a lot to learn, but I'm a little confused here.  Based on that link you provided, it sounds like I need to call it directly, but that's not working:

${Something.url}...

Comment: If you want to use the instance's unique url, you likely want to remove the `static` keyword from `something` instead.

Comment: Yeah, I think I'm finally getting it.  I had a previous ticket where I learned to convert the function to static, but now I've learned I really needed to instantiate the function more correctly.  I have now removed the static keyword and created a new object using the above class name.  Looks like that worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[A static method is shared between all instances of the class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/static), and doesn't have access to a particular instance's variables.

If you want the method to have access to an instance's unique properties, you can remove the `static` keyword and call it on the instance instead of on the class.

**Example**

```js
class Something {
  constructor() {
    this.url = 'domain.com';
  }
  static something(param) {
    const url = `${this.url}/dir/tofile`;
    console.log(url);
  }
}

class SomethingElse {
  constructor() {
    this.url = 'domain.com';
  }
  somethingElse(param) {
    const url = `${this.url}/dir/tofile`;
    console.log(url);
  }
}

const se = new SomethingElse();

Something.something();
se.somethingElse();
```